# Do I need to translate (local) in a sql server connection string?

Tags: sql-server, localization, local

When connecting to sql server, I have the hardcoded string "(local)".  Is this a string I need to make available for localisation?  ie, does (local) always work no matter the current language settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `(local)` and `.` as shortcuts for your local server are *not* language dependent - they're the same for every language and culture - no translations necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works in any locale.

In general, things like function names, connection strings, settings, parameters etc. are rarely localized.

The notable exception is `Excel` functions

In Russian `Excel`, I need to type in function names like `ПРОМЕЖУТОЧНЫЕ.ИТОГИ` instead of `SUBTOTAL`, constantly switch between Latin and Cyrillic (since the column names are still Latin) and I'm unable to copy and paste code developed for English Excel.

Comment: VBA for Excel is considered harmful

Comment: @edosoft: it's not VBA, it's cell functions. VBA is English even in Russian Edition.